# Is it possible to use Zephyr for JIRA only for selected Project?

Tags: testing, plugins, jira, jira-plugin, jira-zephyr

I would like to use Zephyr for JIRA in my project.
I was wondeing if it is possible to use only for selected project? and not for all.
And which version to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar sort of question and spent a chunk of time looking into that.  There are some things you can config on a per project basis, and some you cannot

- **The "test" tab that shows up in the top bar**
  That cannot be configured on a per project basis. If you have zephyr at all, you have that tab.
- **The Test issue type** this can be configured on a per project basis. no problem
- **Price**: this cannot be configured on a per-project basis.

Also, For many questions there are subtle differences between zephyr/jira cloud and zephyr/jira server versions, so if you are asking tech questions I recommend specifying which one you are using. However for the above, the answers are the same for server and cloud